# How can I print the response data in a List?

Tags: list, flutter, http, dio

i am trying to list the data from response.data in a List builder but i can no get parse the data i am getting from the response.
here is the code i want to work with:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

Future getIds() async {
  var response = await Dio().get(
      'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty');
   return response.data;
}



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
List ids = getIds();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getIds();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: ids.length,
        itemBuilder: null);
  }
}
```

how can i do it using dio?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use stateless widget to display data from API. you have to use statefull widget, and return a widget inside item builder

```
itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Text("${ids[index]["yourKey"]}")
 }
```

and also add the function inside init state

```
List ids;
@override
void initState() {
  TODO: implement initState
 super.initState();
 ids = getIds();
```

}

Comment: but how can i use the response data i got?

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions.

- FutureBuilder

  ```
  FutureBuilder(
  future: getIds(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> ids =
        snapshot.data;
      return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: ids.length,
      itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Text("${ids[index]["yourKey"]}")
     });
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return snapshot.error;
    } else {
      return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
    }
  })
  ```
- StatefulWidget

  ```
  setState(() {
    ids = dataList;
  });
  ```